# $f'>0$, $f''>0$ is sufficient for Newton's Method

Tags: numerical-methods, approximation

I'm doing problem 22-14 in Spivak's *Calculus*, 4th edition. Here they outline Newton's method. They assume for convenience that $f'>0$ and $f''>0$, and that $f(x_1)>0$. They note that in this case, if $c< x_1$ is a zero, we have $x_1>x_2>x_3 > \dotsb > c$. Then some analysis follows, and they show that if 
$$x_1-c < \frac{\inf\limits_{x\in [c,x_1]}f'(x)}{\sup\limits_{x\in [c,x_1]}f''(x)}, \tag{*}$$

then Newton's method will work.

Why is the assumption (*) necessary? Already we have $x_n-c$ a positive decreasing sequence, and so it must reach a limit. Plugging into 
$$x_{n+1}=x_n - \frac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)}$$
shows that such a limit must be a zero. Am I missing something, or is this assumption extraneous?

Comment: Looks extraneous to me. I can imagine it helps for obtaining a bound on the rate of convergence, but to prove $x_n\to c$ one does not need (*).